# Frontend for a Python script using React, how to pass variable from HTML input into the python script and open and run it

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have a react frontend where there is a components folder with a button. When the button is pressed I want the link to be sent to a python script that it opens and uses that variable.

```
import React from "react";
function ButtonUse() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form name="search" action="/get-text" method="get">
        <input
          placeholder="https://linkedin.com"
          type="url"
          name="linkedinUrl"
          className="inputs"
        ></input>
         <input type="submit" value="Go"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonUse;
```

```
 from flask import Flask, request, render_template
 import subprocess
 import webbrowser

 chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
 app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../../frontend/src/components')

 @app.route('/')
 def buttonUse():
     return render_template('buttonUse.js')

 @app.route('/get-text', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def myFunction():
     url = request.form['linkedinUrl']

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
     webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open('url')
```

I have tried to use Flask, but the Python file isn't opening.